# Deployment on Vercel File /vercel/path0/backendev/node_modules/transformers/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/exports.js does not exists?

Tags: javascript, express, uglifyjs, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my express-generated backend. But I constantly get this failure. I don't know how or why this is happening.

[image: 1]

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "backendev",
  "version": "0.9.3",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

And here is my vercel.json.

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./app.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "./"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried adding the uglify-js dependencies and deleting the package-lock.json as someone suggested in another forum, but alas, same problem.

What's happening?

UPDATE: I tried creating an Index.js file just to test how it works on vercel and it did work. It seems to be that something is going on with my app.js that is causing the trouble on vercel

Here's the index.js that I used to test:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
        
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Home Page Route'));

app.get('/about', (req, res) => res.send('About Page Route'));

app.get('/portfolio', (req, res) => res.send('Portfolio Page Route'));

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => res.send('Contact Page Route'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on ${port}, http://localhost:${port}`));
```

And Here is my app.js:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors = require('cors');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var backendRouter = require('./routes/backend/index')

var corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200
}

var app = express();

//enable cors
if (process.env.ENABLE_CORS == "1"){
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));
}

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/backend',backendRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: If you run "npm fund", what happening?
And other hand there are 2 node_modules folder which a little bit strange.

Comment: Not much, "npm fund" is just to know which dependencies are accepting donations as support. And about the two node_modules folder, I really don't know. But while checking my Project, that folder called "transformers" does have another node_modules folder inside.

Answer (score 1):

I had a self-inflicted case. i deleted the line

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

in file app.js and it worked. You can try, Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error can vary. You can test the Vercel deploy command locally with debug logs using the following command:

```
vercel build -d
```

Docs for [vercel build](https://vercel.com/docs/cli/build).

In my case, the vercel command was using `yarn install` instead of `npm install`. I updated this in .vercel/project.json like this:

```
{
  "projectId": "{project_id}",
  "orgId": "{org_id}",
  "settings": {
    "createdAt": 1701610725426,
    "framework": null,
    "devCommand": null,
    "installCommand": "npm install",
    "buildCommand": null,
    "outputDirectory": "api",
    "rootDirectory": "src",
    "directoryListing": false,
    "nodeVersion": "18.x"
  }
}
```